# Statistical tests for PRNG that generates a sequence which is not binary

Tags: pseudo-random-function, statistical-test

Is there a pratical application to PRNG that generates a sequence which is not a binary one? A ternary, quaternary sequence, for instance. If so, how can we test this? Is there any alternative test suite, like NIST test suite in order to test the randomness for non-binary sequences? For example, what if I generate a sequence in modulo 255 and then use it to encrypt an image in one-time pad manner via adding the values of pixels by the generated sequence in modulo 255 ?

Comment: Define "non-binary funtion"?

Comment: @fkraiem I mean, when we genarate a sequence whose components are not $0$ and $1$ only, but may be $0,1,2,...,n$. It can be generated by cellular automata (CA) for example.

Comment: This does not matter because a n-ary sequence can be represented as a binary one with only polynomial overhead.

Comment: @fkraiem I think the point is per the test, not how the output can be represented. Since the algorithm may naturally output data in a base that is not 2, a statistical test should be relevant to that particular base, as well as to bitstreams. Ent for example only tests bits and bytes, not arbitrary n-ary sequences

Comment: @RichieFrame  Yes. For example, consider the web site [random.org](http://random.org). We can generate a sequence or a string between a minimum value and a maximum value. How can they test this?

Comment: You just convert it to a binary string and run the test...

Comment: @fkraiem Well, I have some doubt about it. Consider a base, not a power of 2, say 3. The appropriate way representing $0,1,2$ is $00,10,11$ for the sake of respecting the frequency of zeros and ones. However, if we take all $2-$tuples in base 3 and covert them to binary we have $0000,0010,0011,1000,1010,1011,1100,1110,1111$. Isn't it a handicap that absence of some binary $4-$tuples ?

Comment: Not at all; why would it?

Comment: @fkraiem Is expected value of $01$ still same, or the probability of its occurance?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Because converting from n-ary to binary or vice versa can be done in poly time, any test for n-ary strings can trivially be modified to operate on binary strings, and vice versa.

Comment: @fkraiem I mean: The probability of occurance of $0000$ for instance is $1/16$ if we generate a binary string in spite of the fact that same probability is $1/7$ if we take representations of ternary strings. And still I think it is a weakness.

Comment: Well you are free to "think" whatever you want...

Comment: I have an idea but that should be scrutinized by the experts, since I am not a mathematician. Let the alphabet of the given sequence be A1. Supplement that with an alphabet A2 such that A=A1+A2 has a size of a power of 2. Let L1 be the length of the given sequence S1. Let S2 be a random sequence of elements in A2 of length L2 such that L=L1+L2 is a multiple of the size of A. Now in random locations of a sequence S of length L put randomly selected elements of A2 and in the remaining locations put in elements of S1 in the order given. The test statistic of S should IMHO be ok for your purposes.

Comment: [correction to my last post:] Please read instead of "such that L=L1+L2 is a multiple of the size of A." the following: "such that L=L1+L2 is a multiple of the size of A and L1/L2 is equal to the size of A1 divided by the size of A2." Note that the described construction aims to have a correct proportion of the elements of A2 in their (sort of) "natural" locations (as required by ideal randomness) such that the deviations from ideal randomness of the given sequence S1 would be adequately shown up in the test statistic of S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Randomness testing uses asymptotic properties. Thus, as the length of your input increases the effect you are concerned about will disappear.

Specifically, there is no need to convert ternary $1$ or $2-$tuples to binary. If you let $n$ increase you cover the interval $\{0,1,\ldots,3^n-1\}$ and then you convert these integers to binary, paying at most a 1 trit (Shannon's term for entropy in base 3) penalty in entropy. Since a decent ternary source should yield not much less than $$\left(\frac{\log 3}{\log 2}\right)n$$ bits or $n$ trits of entropy, there is nothing to worry about.